# Find Count of Elements from One List in Another List

Tags: r

So, if I have two lists, one being a "master list" without repeats, and the other being a subset with possible repeats, I would like to be able to check how many of each element are in the secondary subset list.

So if I have these lists:

```
a <- (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
b <- (a, d, c, d, a, f, f, g, c, c)
```

I'd like to determine how many times each element from list `a` appear in list `b` and the frequency of each.  My ideal output would be an r table that looks like:

```
c <- a b c d e f g 
     2 0 3 1 0 2 1
```

I've been trying to think through it with `%in%` and `table()`

Comment: `sapply(a, function(x) sum(b %in% x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table` and `match` - but first make the vectors factors so levels not present are included in the output:

```
a <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"))
b <- factor(c("a", "d", "c", "d", "a", "f", "f", "g", "c", "c"))

table(a[match(b, a)])

a b c d e f g 
2 0 3 2 0 2 1
```

Comment: or also `table(factor(c('a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'c'), levels=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")))`

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you want a tidyverse solution. This method preserves the original data type in the lists.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
b <- c("a", "d", "c", "d", "a", "f", "f", "g", "c", "c")

tibble(letters = a, count = unlist(map(a, function(x) sum(b %in% x))))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
 letters count
<chr>   <int>
1 a           2
2 b           0
3 c           3
4 d           2
5 e           0
6 f           2
7 g           1
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Error: ``tribble()`` needs to specify at least one column using the ``~name`` syntax.`
Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Try `tibble()` not `tribble()`

Comment: If you want to use tribble check this out: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/tribble